# Exception handling pseudocode (try-catch) for algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

It appears that there is no such `try` and `catch` blocks in algorithm2e. Is there a way to add custom blocks for `try` and `catch` in algorithm2e?

There is a [solution](https://gist.github.com/DrDougPhD/74ef412516e6ef760da1618b64d6ee59) in GitHub which shows how this can be done using the algorithmicx/algpseudocode package. I would like to do this in algorithm2e.

Answer (score 4):

Took a better look at the [docs](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) and found an applicable solution:
 `\SetKwProg{Cmd}{block}{suffix}{end}`
The `suffix` and `end` parts are optional

A minimum working example (MWE):

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
  \SetKwProg{try}{try}{:}{}
  \SetKwProg{catch}{catch}{:}{end}
  \Input{Array $a$ and index $i$}
  \Output{what the procedure returns}

  \try{}{
    $v \gets a[i]$
  }
  \catch{IndexOutOfBoundsException}{
    $v \gets -1$
  }
  \Return $v$
  \caption{Exception handling code}
  \label{alg:exep}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone else think it would be better without the colon suffix?